# TensorFlow incompatible function arguments in making Elbo

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, time-series

Pardon me for being lazy about this, but I'm not getting the answer anywhere.
I'm trying to replicate the exercise here in my own computer: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand.ipynb

However, I'm getting stuck at this part:

```
# Build and optimize the variational loss function.
elbo_loss_curve = tfp.vi.fit_surrogate_posterior(
    target_log_prob_fn=co2_model.joint_distribution(
        observed_time_series=co2_by_month_training_data).log_prob,
    surrogate_posterior=variational_posteriors,
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    num_steps=num_variational_steps,
    jit_compile=True)

plt.plot(elbo_loss_curve)
plt.show()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: TF_TryEvaluateConstant_wrapper(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Graph, arg1: tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Output) -> object

Invoked with: <tensorflow.python.framework.c_api_util.ScopedTFGraph object at 0x0000024EDCF90C70>, <tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Output object at 0x0000024EDD26DBB0>
```

Anyone knows what the cause is? I get that there's a problem with my input but i'm looking for a fix.